# 2 separate trips to Schengen a month apart - How to mention dates of entry and leave?

Tags: visas, schengen, international-travel

I am travelling to Europe in June and August respectively. Poland in June for 4 days and Germany in August for 6-7 days followed by 2 days each in Netherland and Belgium. I am stuck in the application form at a particular field. What should I enter as my dates of entry and leave? I will be entering Poland in June and going to UK from there and back to India by June end, whereas I will be entering Germany in August and exiting from Belgium in about 11 days.

I already have acquired the UK visa.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the dates for your first trip, Poland, and only add the details for those other days only if you can apply for two trips on the one form.

The dates for your Germany, Belgium and Netherlands trip should be posted in one block, entry into Germany, leave from Belgium. If you can not add on the same form you may need to apply twice.

Comment: Hey thanks! I had some trouble at VFS. They clearly told me that since my entry is Poland, and the longest stay is Germany, and there is a break in trip, my Visa could get rejected. As an attempt to convince the embassy I had to write an application explaining my situation. Got it, within 4 days. Had an awesome trip!